# What should I do with a non-English answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, languages

In the review queue, I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603883/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-oracle-10g-database-from-c-sharp-program-employi/20292763#20292763) that is not in English

> Si estás intentando conectarte a una base de datos Oracle a través de un WCF, reinicia el IIS , para esto, abrir el cmd y ejecutar la sentencia iisreset.

Using [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/#auto/en/Si%20est%C3%A1s%20intentando%20conectarte%20a%20una%20base%20de%20datos%20Oracle%20a%20trav%C3%A9s%20de%20un%20WCF,%20reinicia%20el%20IIS%20,%20para%20esto,%20abrir%20el%20cmd%20y%20ejecutar%20la%20sentencia%20iisreset.), the answer in English is

> If you are trying to connect to an Oracle database through a WCF restart the IIS for this, open the cmd and run the iisreset judgment.

This answer might be useful for the OP an other users so what should I do with it.

Should I edit the answer and change to English or leave it?

**Update :** I already flagged the answer. Is that enough?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209169/should-edits-that-run-a-foreign-language-post-through-google-translate-be-approv

Comment: @Undo Thanks!!. Voted to close

Comment: @Downvoter. What is there in this post to disagree with?

Comment: Meh, the drive-by downvote is common here at Meta. Remember that votes have a different meaning here. Downvotes show up where they're least expected.

Comment: @Undo You're right. I've noticed drive-by downvotes on many of my meta posts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're under no obligation to do anything more than flag it for not being in English. Since you've taken the time to translate it, you could then paste the translation into the question, either as well as the original or (better) in place of it. The edit summary could be "translated into English" if you like. However make it actually English: I think that's the `iisreset` command, not judgment.

Comment: `command <> judgment`..... you mean Google Translate isn't perfect?

Comment: Agreed - I would think it better to _add_ the translation; especially if it is a google translate and you do not speak it yourself. Google translate can be a bit of an extreme sport at times. I would add the google translation, and highlight that that is what it is.